# Powershell - Get value of text box on web page and save as txt file

Tags: powershell, html

I am currently scripting something that will go to a certain web page. Once on the web page it will click the run button which will calculate a value on the webpage and put it in a read only text area with the id="result Console". The code that does this is below:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("https://example.com/example.aspx")

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}   

$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.className -eq "runButton"}

$Link.click()
```

After it does the above I need to get the text that is in the text area and save it to a txt file.

I was wondering if this was possible and if so how I would go about doing so?

I presume I could get the text from the text area in to a variable and then export this using the below command:

```
$example | out-file -filepath C:\temp\example.txt
```

I would appreciate any help you can give on this.

Thanks in advance,

SG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `textarea` has an `id` value set, I guess you can use the `getElementById` with the `id` as parameter:

```
$example = $ie.Document.getElementById("id of the textarea")

$example.value #should have the text you want to write to the txt file
```

It's been a while I wrote Powershell script but I remember doing it this way last time I needed the text from a `textarea`.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! Genius, the only thing I had to change to make it work was it's element not elements. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  Sodawillow and user3290171. Have fun.